# Запрос из нескольких таблиц со скрытием столбца C++

Tags: c++, sql, запрос

Есть запрос вида:

```
SELECT t1.id_employees, t1.fio_employees, t2.title_post, t1.date_employees
FROM employees t1 
INNER JOIN post t2 ON t1.post_id_employees = t2.id_post
```

С помощью `ADOQuery` я заполняю грид указанными столбцами из данного запроса. 
При этом мне нужно получить из таблицы `employees` содержимое столбца `post_id_employees`, которого в этом запросе нет, чтобы занести его значения в массив. Собственно, в этом и проблема: я не знаю как мне получить этот столбец, чтобы во время работы запроса он не отображался в гриде, а просто записался в массив и все.

Единственное, что приходит на ум - это первоначально, перед вызовом и открытием формы, программно выполнить запрос, заполнить массив, затем очистить `ADOQuery` и уже в него написать второй запрос - тот, что выше, дабы заполнить грид и дальше с этим `ADOQuery` работать.

Если что, первоначально этот sql-запрос написан в свойстве SQL компонента `ADOQuery`, а не в коде.
Заполнять массив пытаюсь так:

```
id_client_array[ADOQuery5->RecordCount];
arr_copy[ADOQuery5->RecordCount];
for(int i = 0; i < ADOQuery5->RecordCount; i++)
{
  ComboBox4->Items->Add(ADOQuery5->FieldValues["fio_employees"]);
  ComboBox5->Items->Add(ADOQuery5->FieldValues["title_post"]);
  id_client_array[i] =  ADOQuery5->FieldValues["id_employees"];
  arr_copy[i] =  ADOQuery5->FieldValues["post_id_employees"]; //На этом месте ошибка, пишет, что этот столбец отсутствует в ADOQuery
  ADOQuery5->Next();
}
```